# how to remove the XML Declaration from Opera when using XMLSerializer

Tags: javascript, opera, xmlserializer

in Opera when I serialize an xml doc, it returns the string with the XML Declaration added to it. In Firefox and Chrome this dose not occur, and i would like Opera to return same results as Firefox and Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/superbDeveloper/Qst5e/9/ (JavaScript Code below)

**JavaScript Code**

```
//test xml serializer
var s = new XMLSerializer();  
var d = document;  
var str = s.serializeToString(d);  
console.log("1)  serializeToString "); 
console.log(str);
```

**Results in Firefox**

```
1) serializeToString
<!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" /> <title> - jsFiddle demo by superbDeveloper</title> <script src="/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.2-full-nocompat.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <link href="/css/normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link href="/css/result-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> <style type="text/css"> </style>.....
```

**Results in Opera**

```
1)  serializeToString 
<?xml version="1.0"?><html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.2-full-nocompat.js"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"/>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>...
```

Notice the XML Declaration `<?xml version="1.0"?>` has being added in Opera browser. Is there a way of stoping Opera from adding the XML Declaration? or how can one remove the XML Declaration? I thought of using `substring` but its not really an elegant solution.

Comment: using substring method http://jsfiddle.net/superbDeveloper/Qst5e/11/ works fine. not sure if its an elegant solution tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at this point what you have is a string, so using string methods is as elegant as it gets :)

I'm not aware of any other way to do it.

Comment: ya i must say substring method http://jsfiddle.net/superbDeveloper/Qst5e/11/ works well so ya I'm gonna stick with it. thanks for clarify tho.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is only in non-IE browser. Use documentElement solution.

```
xmlData = jQuery(xmlData);
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();

if (typeof xmlData[0].documentElement !== 'undefined') {
  var xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(xmlData[0].documentElement);
} else {
  var xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(xmlData[0]);
}
```